# API replacement for our collaborative LaTeX gadget

Tags: editors

My team created [LaTeX gadget](https://rizzoma.com/topic/1284dbfc45cff06a43e40bfe14a281cd/0_b_3f5o_2nnqp/) as a part of our groupwork web service - Rizzoma. To draw LaTeX formulas, we're using Google Charts API now: it's simple and sufficient, but supports input up to 200 characters only. 
Is there any LaTeX API which we can use as a replacement to Google one?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It doesn't use TeX but parses a lot of latex syntax,  you probably want to look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)

Comment: I would also have a look at [graph.tk](http://graph.tk/).  It's source is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/aantthony/graph.tk).  (For digging's sake.)

Answer (score 3):

Any mathematical formula that could be rendered can be rendered with MathJax. MathJax works, basically, in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
This is text.<br/>
Inline math: \( a_x + 5 = b_x \)<br/>
Display math:
\[ \delta_x = \sqrt{\frac{5x}{2b}} \]
</body>
</html>
```

Which results in: (Firefox, Mac OS 10.8)

[image: mathjax]

While you don't have a picture (the formula is 'rendered' as two-dimensional text onscreen), it does render fine in almost all browsers.  For a fine example of its practical use, have a look at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

For more information explore the [MathJax website](http://www.mathjax.org/).